# Each components not sharing an instances of a service

Tags: angular

**Goal:** I am trying to create an service that has a subscribe-able array (BehaviorSubject) so that when I update the data in the service the changes are reflected in the client components that are using it. I decide to first try keeping a persistence list of in the server when an item is appended or changed, then later I will worry about keeping the data consistent with the server.

**Problem:**

workCategories:Rx.BehaviorSubject> in the service does not seem to keep it's data it's assigned. When it is called from the 1st client component and then when the service is used by a 2nd client component, workCategories is null again.

**service**

```
import { Component, Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, RequestMethod, Request } from "@angular/http";
import { WorkCategory } from "./models";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import * as Rx from "rxjs/Rx";


@Injectable()
export class WorkCategoryService {

    public workCategories: Rx.BehaviorSubject<Array<WorkCategory>>;

    private _workCategories: Array<WorkCategory> = [];

    constructor(public http: Http) {
        console.log("!!!!WorkCat Service Constructor Called!!!");
        this.getWorkCategories();
    }

    addWorkCategory(wc: WorkCategory): number {
        //** when this is called after component is instantiated and getWorkCategories() is called this.workCategories is null
        console.log("Add Work Category Called in Service for \"" + wc.name + "\"");

        let newID: number;
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        let blah = this.http.post('./api/workcategories', JSON.stringify(wc), options).subscribe((res: Response) => newID = res.json());
        if (this._workCategories != null) {
            console.log("Added to private");
            this._workCategories.push(wc);
        }

        //** fails here and the page is reloaded due to this.workCategories being null
        this.workCategories.next(this._workCategories);

        return newID;
    }

    getWorkCategories(): Observable<Array<WorkCategory>> {
        console.log("Get Work Category Called in Service");

        var blah = this.http.get('./api/workcategories')
            .map(this.WorkCategoriesResponseMapper)
        console.log("Get Work Category Done in Service");
        return blah;

    }

    WorkCategoriesResponseMapper(response: Response) {
        var temp = response.json();

        if (this.workCategories == null) {            
            this._workCategories = temp;           
            this.workCategories = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(this._workCategories);  
        }
        else {
            this._workCategories = temp;
            this.workCategories.next(this._workCategories);
        }
        return temp;
    }
}
```

**1st client component**

this calls  this.workCatServ.getWorkCategories() and subscribes to it.

```
import { Component, Input, Injectable, ViewChild, EventEmitter, Output, } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, RequestMethod, Request } from "@angular/http";
import { WorkCategory } from "./models";
import { WorkCategoryService } from "./workcategories.service";
//import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as Rx from "rxjs/Rx";
import { TreeNode, MenuItem, Message } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { CategoryAdderUpdateComponent } from "./category-adder-update.component";


@Component({
    selector: 'workcategories_view',
    //providers: [WorkCategoryService],
    templateUrl: './app/workcategories-view.html'
})

@Injectable()
export class WorkCategoriesViewComponent {
    @ViewChild(CategoryAdderUpdateComponent) private CategoryCU: CategoryAdderUpdateComponent;
    @Output() GrowlMsg = new EventEmitter<Message>();
    workCats: Array<WorkCategory>;
    tree: TreeNode[];
    selectedNode: TreeNode;
    selectedCategory: WorkCategory = new WorkCategory(-1,"Blank",-2);
    contextMenuItems: MenuItem[];
    CUWorkCatVisible: boolean = false;
    CUWorkCatEdit: boolean = false;
    CUViewHeader: string;

    constructor(public http: Http, private workCatServ: WorkCategoryService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("Work Categories view called");
        this.workCatServ.getWorkCategories().subscribe(result => this.convertToTreeNodes(result), error => console.error(error), () => { });

        this.contextMenuItems = [
            {
                label: 'Add',
                icon: 'fa-plus',
                command: (event) => { this.displayAddWorkCat() }
            },
            {
                label: 'Edit',
                icon: 'fa-edit',
                command: (event) => { this.displayEditWorkCat() }        
            },
            {
                label: 'Delete',
                icon: 'fa-eraser',
                command: (event) => { this.displayDeleteWorkCat() } 

            }
        ];

    }


    displayAddWorkCat() {

        this.selectedCategory = this.workCats.find(b => b.id == this.selectedNode.data);
        //console.log("Add " + this.selectedCategory.name);
        this.CategoryCU.AddView(this.selectedCategory);
        this.CUViewHeader = "Add Work Category";
        /*this.workCatServ.findWorkCategorey(this.selectedNode.data).map(result => {
            console.log("Done");
            this.selectedCategory = result;

        });
        */

        this.CUWorkCatVisible = true;

    }

    displayEditWorkCat() {                
        this.selectedCategory = this.workCats.find(x => x.id == this.selectedNode.data);
        //console.log("Edit " + this.selectedCategory.name);
        this.CategoryCU.UpdateView(this.selectedCategory);
        this.CUViewHeader = "Edit \"" + this.selectedCategory.name + "\" Work Category";

        /*this.workCatServ.findWorkCategory(this.selectedNode.data).map(result => {
            console.log("Done");
            this.selectedCategory = result;

        });*/

        this.CUWorkCatVisible = true;

    }

    displayDeleteWorkCat() {
        console.log("Delete");

    }

    passUpGrowlMsg(msg: Message) {
        this.GrowlMsg.emit(msg);
    }

    MyTreeWalker(nodeId: number = 0, parentNode: TreeNode = null): boolean {
        let blah = this.workCats.filter(x => x.parentId == nodeId);
        if (blah.length == 0) {
            //console.log("Node " + nodeId + " is leaf");
            return false;
        }

        //console.log("Node " + nodeId + " is branch, " + blah.length + " children");


        if (nodeId != 0) {

            for (var b of blah) {
                var TempNode: TreeNode = { label: b.name, data: b.id, parent: parentNode, children: [] };

                this.MyTreeWalker(b.id, TempNode);
                //console.log("Control Passed Back");
                parentNode.children.push(TempNode);
                //console.log("Pass End");
            }
        } else {
            for (var c of blah) {
                var TempNode: TreeNode = { label: c.name, data: c.id, parent: parentNode, children: [] };
                this.MyTreeWalker(c.id, TempNode);
                //console.log("R - Control Passed Back");
                this.tree.push(TempNode);
                //console.log("R - Pass End");
            }                      
        }
        //console.log("Node: " + nodeId + " Exit");
        return true;
    }

    convertToTreeNodes(cats: WorkCategory[]) {
        console.log("Tree Updated Called");
        this.tree = new Array<TreeNode>();
        this.workCats = cats;

        this.MyTreeWalker();
    }
}
```

**2nd client components**

this calls addWorkCategory() in the service

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Response } from "@angular/http";
import { WorkCategory} from "./models";
import { WorkCategoryService } from "./workcategories.service";
import { Message } from 'primeng/primeng';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
    selector: 'category-adder-update',
    //providers: [WorkCategoryService],
    templateUrl: './app/category-adder-update.html'

})

export class CategoryAdderUpdateComponent {

    @Output() GrowlMsg = new EventEmitter<Message>();
    edit: boolean;
    workcategories: Array<WorkCategory> = [];
    tempCategory: WorkCategory;
    parentCategory: WorkCategory;
    buttonText: string = "Blanky Blank";



    constructor(public http: Http, public workCategoriesServ: WorkCategoryService) {
        this.tempCategory = new WorkCategory(null,"",null);
        console.log("Category Adder-Update Called");
    }

    AddView(parentCat: WorkCategory) {
        this.edit = false;
        this.parentCategory = parentCat
        this.tempCategory = new WorkCategory(null, "", parentCat.id);
        this.buttonText = "Add Work Category";

    }

    UpdateView(cat: WorkCategory) {
        this.edit = true;
        this.parentCategory = null;
        this.tempCategory = cat;
        this.buttonText = "Update Work Category";
    }

    blahSubmit() {
        if (this.edit) {
            this.updateWorkCategory();
        } else {
            this.addWorkCategory();
        }
    }


    getWorkCategories() {
        console.log("jobs get called");
        this.workCategoriesServ.getWorkCategories().subscribe(
            result => this.workcategories = result,
            error => console.error,
            () => console.log('workcategories loaded: ' + this.workcategories.length));
    }

    addWorkCategory(): void {    
        this.GrowlMsg.emit({ severity: 'info', summary: 'Category Added', detail: "Category " + this.tempCategory.name + " added to " + this.parentCategory.name });       
        if (this.workCategoriesServ.addWorkCategory(this.tempCategory) != null) {
            console.log("New Work Category Submitted");
        }
        else {
            console.error("New Work Category NOT Submitted");
        }

    }


}
```

**App Module**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule, FormsModule, DataTableModule, CalendarModule, TreeModule, TabViewModule, GrowlModule, DialogModule, ContextMenuModule, RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes) ], 
    declarations: [AppComponent, TicketAdderComponent, JobsViewComponent, TimeEntriesViewComponent, WorkCategoriesViewComponent, CategoryAdderUpdateComponent],
    providers: [WorkCategoryService],
    entryComponents: [TicketAdderComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: It's not very persistent as it seams to be.

Comment: @RomanC Whjat does that mean?

Comment: In computer science, persistence refers to the characteristic of state that outlives the process that created it. This is achieved in practice by storing the state as data in computer data storage. Programs have to transfer data to and from storage devices and have to provide mappings from the native programming-language data structures to the storage device data structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are Providing the service in each component.  What you want to do is provide the service in AppModule, then both components will share the same service.

Comment: I have commented out WorkCategoryService as a provider in both components and  added it to AppModule, I still have the same result.

Comment: @TheColonel26 It is highly unlikely that it will be the same result, because this is how A2 DI works. The answer is correct on that, I would suggest to double check that you've applied these changes to the code you're running in browser. Otherwise the question needs [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that can replicate the issue.